# Error Mounting CIFS share on CentOS7.6 kernel 4.20, mount error(22): Invalid argument

Tags: linux, cifs

I am trying to mount CIFS share from NetApp (Release 8.2.4P6 7-Mode) on CentOS7. I tried `sec=ntlm` which suppose to work but it says an invalid argument and if I change it to `vers=1.0` which I think server throwing permission deny error because it required authentication.

It `(vers=2.0 -o sec=ntlm)` works on RHEL 6.9 kernal 2.6 OS

```
[root@Myhost ~]#  mount -v -t cifs -o vers=2.0 -o sec=ntlm -o credentials=/etc/samba/credentials.conf //cifsshare.mydomain.com/Test/V23/Marketing /mnt/test
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.1.5.21,unc=\\cifsshare.mydomain.com\Test,vers=2.0,sec=ntlm,user=mydomain\username,prefixpath=V23/Marketing,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)


[root@Myhost ~]#  mount -v -t cifs -o vers=1.0 -o sec=ntlm -o credentials=/etc/samba/credentials.conf //cifsshare.mydomain.com/Test/V23/Marketing /mnt/test
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.1.5.21,unc=\\cifsshare.mydomain.com\Test,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,user=mydomain\username,prefixpath=V23/Marketing,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: ver=1 is not supported in Windows by default anymore.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro how about sec=ntlm. why it is saying invalid argument on CentOS7

Comment: Does installing cifs-utils or using IP address instead of name work?

Comment: Nop, already tried that

Comment: You mention kernel version 4.20 which is not standard for CentOS 7.6, so I am not sure what configuration it is using.  Have you verified that CIFS has been enabled in your kernel (`CONFIG_CIFS`) or if you have the required kernel modules loaded?

Comment: @GracefulRestart I had no reason to update to this kernel but in my initial research, someone mentioned in one of the forum that there is a bug and I should use this version. let me know the version that works.. and I will that one.

Comment: I don't have access to RHEL subscription but it looks like this might have a solution.. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3354541

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro how about if I downgrade mount.cifs to 4.8 ?

Comment: Presumably there are error logs available on the Filer. That would be your next point of call.

Comment: Try to remove the `vers` option